# How to set tintColor for the whole app in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, tintcolor

In iOS you can set a `tintColor` for the whole app like this:

```
window.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

In which `window` is the key `UIWindow` of the app. How can this be achieved in React Native, so that you can avoid setting it all over the app like in the following examples:

```
StackNavigator({
...
}, {
...
    navigationOptions: {
        headerTintColor: '#000',
    }
});
```

OR:

```
tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => {
...
}, 
drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => {
...
}
```